# MemoryError in sentence clustering in Python

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, cluster-analysis

I have 1 million sentences. I am using Affinity Propagation algorithm to cluster similar sentence together. I am facing issue in processing such large data and getting Memory Error.

Error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        72 # ]
>        73 
>   ---> 74 clusters = get_clusters(sentences)
>        75 #print(clusters)
>        76
>
> in get_clusters(sentences)
>        18 def get_clusters(sentences):
>        19     tf_idf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences)
>   ---> 20     similarity_matrix = (tf_idf_matrix * tf_idf_matrix.T).A
>        21     affinity_propagation = AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
>        22     affinity_propagation.fit(similarity_matrix)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in
>   **getattr**(self, attr)
>       562     def **getattr**(self, attr):
>       563         if attr == 'A':
>   --> 564             return self.toarray()
>       565         elif attr == 'T':
>       566             return self.transpose()
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in
>   toarray(self, order, out)
>       962     def toarray(self, order=None, out=None):
>       963         """See the docstring for `spmatrix.toarray`."""
>   --> 964         return self.tocoo(copy=False).toarray(order=order, out=out)
>       965 
>       966     ##############################################################
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py in
>   toarray(self, order, out)
>       250     def toarray(self, order=None, out=None):
>       251         """See the docstring for `spmatrix.toarray`."""
>   --> 252         B = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
>       253         fortran = int(B.flags.f_contiguous)
>       254         if not fortran and not B.flags.c_contiguous:
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in
>   _process_toarray_args(self, order, out)    1037             return out    1038         else:
>   -> 1039             return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)    1040     1041     def **numpy_ufunc**(self, func,
>   method, pos, inputs, **kwargs):
>
> MemoryError:

Code:

```
import nltk, string
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)
stemmer = nltk.stem.snowball.SpanishStemmer()

def stem_tokens(tokens):
    return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]

def normalize(text):
    return stem_tokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(punctuation_map)))

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize)

def get_clusters(sentences):
    tf_idf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences)
    similarity_matrix = (tf_idf_matrix * tf_idf_matrix.T).A
    affinity_propagation = AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
    affinity_propagation.fit(similarity_matrix)

    labels = affinity_propagation.labels_

    cluster_centers = affinity_propagation.cluster_centers_indices_

    tagged_sentences = zip(sentences, labels)
    clusters = {}

    for sentence, cluster_id in tagged_sentences:
        clusters.setdefault(sentences[cluster_centers[cluster_id]], []).append(sentence)

    return clusters


#loading data file
filename = "/home/ubuntu/VA_data/first_50K.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header = None)

sentences = df.iloc[:, 0].values.tolist()

clusters = get_clusters(sentences)

#print cluster labels in descending order of number sentences present in it 
for k in sorted(clusters, key=lambda k: len(clusters[k]), reverse=True):
        print(k,"\n")

#Print cluster with sentences in it
for cluster in clusters:
    print(cluster, ':')
    count = 0
    for element in clusters[cluster]:
        print('  - ', element)
        count+= 1
    print('Cluster size: ', count)
    print('% of queries within the cluster', (count/len(sentences))*100)

print('Number of clusters: ',len(cluster_centers))
```

How I should resolve this issue? Please help

Comment: Buy more RAM perhaps?

Comment: @Mad: I have 16GB RAM and 64 bit system and Ubuntu

Comment: You should probably edit that into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Affinity propagation needs two asymmetric n by n matrixes. Your input matrix is another copy.

Do the math: what amount of memory do you need for n=1 million and double precision times three matrixes (maybe there will even be yet another copy)? Do you have enough memory for TBs of distance data?

Otherwise, you should probably use an algorithm that does *not* use a distance matrix.

Comment: I did not get you exactly. Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: When you write code like this: `(tf_idf_matrix * tf_idf_matrix.T)`, it will *never* scale to large data. Compute how much *memory* you need to store the result, and you'll see why such algorithms *cannot* scale. So the error is correct: *your* program asks for more memory than you have.

Comment: Thank you Anony for you help. As I am new to python, can you suggest code changes that I need to do?

Comment: No. Because that will not increase your system memory to a few TB if you change your code. Don't blame it on python, if you want to do something impossible.

Comment: I am not blaming Python. I am just new to this, so wanted to explore new ways.

Comment: It is not related to Python. This is universal. A n x n matrix will need n*n*sizeof(datatype) bytes at best. In fact, if you use Python arrays it will take much more than this. But numpy arrays are reasonably close to the minimum at least for huge arrays.

Answer (score 1):

@Sonal, I just recently hit this problem as well (which is why I'm here). If you want to test applying what [Anony-Mousse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060350/anony-mousse) is suggesting, consider scaling down your data with something like `sentences = sentences.head(n=20)`. If everything else is written correctly, this will run successfully for you. But as you increase the value of `n` you will eventually hit this same `MemoryError`. To Anony-Mousse's point, this is a legitimate system limitation and Python is telling you up-front that your system cannot run this many calculations. Most likely, this can only be worked-around by changing hardware or changing your choice of clustering.

I'm a beginner too, so don't take this for gospel :) hoping this helps you keep iterating!